# Getting Firefox URL

Tags: c#, firefox

I need to know the URL on which the user currently is.(with Firefox)
I thought of a keylogger to keep track of the URL, but what when the user clicks a link?

The title is not enough, I need the complete URL.
With IE this is easy, but with Firefox it isn't.
for IE I'm using:

```
private string GetUrlFromIE()
{
IntPtr windowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
IntPtr childHandle;
String strUrlToReturn = "";

//IE's toolbar container
childHandle = FindWindowEx(windowHandle,IntPtr.Zero,"WorkerW",IntPtr.Zero);
if(childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    //get a handle to address bar
    childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle,IntPtr.Zero,"ReBarWindow32",IntPtr.Zero);
    if(childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // get a handle to combo boxes
        childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBoxEx32", IntPtr.Zero);
        if(childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // get a handle to combo box
            childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", IntPtr.Zero);
            if(childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //get handle to edit
                childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", IntPtr.Zero);
                if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    strUrlToReturn = GetText(childHandle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return strUrlToReturn;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: well in IE you can get the url by getting the handle of the adressbar, and then using WINAPI getWindowText() you can retrieve IEs url, but firefox doesnt have child handles, at least no child handles whose getwindowtext would return something else than 0

Comment: @Dan This question is tagged C# (and not JavaScript)

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us EXACTLY what you're trying to do, and how you're doing it.

Comment: Your question is vague, and your requirements aren't clear. We have only now gleaned how you're trying to get the information you want through your comment. Are you using a C# win app to get the location from an external web browser?

Comment: Yes I am using a c# winforms app and trying to get the location on wich firefox currently is.

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137880/how-can-you-automate-firefox-from-c-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, you can access the URL by way of

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: how could i run that in firefox without changing the url?

Comment: It only changes the url if you set it to something. To get the url, you can:

    var theUrl = window.location.href;

It only redirects the user if you set it to something

    window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

Comment: yes but how can I run that script in firefox? if i run file:///.../script.js or something like that ill gonna chage the url

Answer (score 3):

You can get the URL using Windows **IAccessible** interface.

For easy IAccessible manipulation I'll suggest to use **[Managed Windows API](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/)** library.
You should have FireFox window handle in advance.

Here is C# code to grab the URL from FireFox:

```
    private static string GetUrlFromFirefox(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        SystemAccessibleObject sao = SystemAccessibleObject.FromWindow(new SystemWindow(windowHandle), AccessibleObjectID.OBJID_WINDOW);
        var preds = new Predicate<SystemAccessibleObject>[] { 
            s => s.RoleString == "application",
            s => s.RoleString == "property page",
            s => s.RoleString == "grouping" && s.StateString == "None",
            s => s.RoleString == "property page" && s.StateString == "None",
            s => s.RoleString == "browser",
            s => s.RoleString == "document" && s.Visible
        };

        var current = sao.Children;
        SystemAccessibleObject child = null;
        foreach (var pred in preds)
        {
            child = Array.Find(current, pred);
            if (child != null)
            {
                current = child.Children;
            }
        }

        if (child != null)
        {
            return child.Value;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

This works for FireFox 14.