# How can i fill a C# listview by using foreach loop a column and another foreach for second column so that 2nd loop do not over write first

Tags: c#

I am extracting url and url time for two registry key. And wants to show it in list view.
Using to loops how can i fill listview first column by a loop an second by another because both url and time is in diffrent reg keys.....

```
listViewCookies.Columns.Add("TYPED URL", 300);

listViewCookies.Columns.Add("TIME", 400);

string[] url = new string[2];
ListViewItem item;

using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(strSID + @"\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs"))
{
  try
  {
    foreach (string u in rk.GetValueNames())
    {
       url[0] = rk.GetValue(u).ToString();
    }
  }
  catch { }
}

using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(strSID + @"\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLsTime"))
{
  try
  {
    foreach (string u in rk.GetValueNames())
    {
      object val = rk.GetValue(u);
      DateTime output = DateTime.MinValue;
      if (val is byte[] && ((byte[])val).Length == 8)
      {
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])val;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ft = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME();
        int valLow = bytes[0] + 256 * (bytes[1] + 256 * (bytes[2] + 256 * bytes[3]));
        int valTwo = bytes[4] + 256 * (bytes[5] + 256 * (bytes[6] + 256 * bytes[7]));
        ft.dwLowDateTime = valLow;
        ft.dwHighDateTime = valTwo;
        DateTime UTC = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((((long)ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime);
        TimeZoneInfo lcl = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        TimeZoneInfo utc = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
        output = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(UTC, utc, lcl);
        url[1] = output.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
  catch { }
}

item = new ListViewItem(url);
listViewCookies.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: why don't You use a hashtable as buffer between reading the values and filling them into the listview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing a new `ListViewItem` you can construct it at the beginning:

```
 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
```

Then if you want to set the first column:

```
 item.Text = "url ..." // Column 0 (Url)
```

To set the second column:

```
 item.SubItems.Add("time..."); // Column 1 (Time)
```

Then, at the end, add the `ListViewItem` to the list view:

```
 listViewCookies.Items.Add(item);
```

Edit, here's a modified example:

```
   listViewCookies.Columns.Add("TYPED URL", 300);
   listViewCookies.Columns.Add("TIME", 400);

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();


        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(strSID + @"\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs"))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string u in rk.GetValueNames())
                {

                    item.Text = rk.GetValue(u).ToString();


                }
            }
            catch { }
        }


        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(strSID + @"\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLsTime"))
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string u in rk.GetValueNames())
                {

                    object val = rk.GetValue(u);

                    DateTime output = DateTime.MinValue;
                    if (val is byte[] && ((byte[])val).Length == 8)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = (byte[])val;

                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ft = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME();
                        int valLow = bytes[0] + 256 * (bytes[1] + 256 * (bytes[2] + 256 * bytes[3]));
                        int valTwo = bytes[4] + 256 * (bytes[5] + 256 * (bytes[6] + 256 * bytes[7]));
                        ft.dwLowDateTime = valLow;
                        ft.dwHighDateTime = valTwo;

                        DateTime UTC = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((((long)ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime);
                        TimeZoneInfo lcl = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
                        TimeZoneInfo utc = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
                        output = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(UTC, utc, lcl);

                        item.SubItems.Add(output.ToString());

                    }
                }
            }

            catch { }
        }

        listViewCookies.Items.Add(item);

    }
```

Comment: The first `foreach` will repeatedly set the `Text` of the item, over and over again, losing the previous value.

Answer (score 2):

After stripping the unrelated code you are left with something like:

```
string[] url = new string[2];

foreach (string u in someCollection)
{
   url[0] = someValue(u);
}

foreach (string u in someOtherCollection)
{
    url[1] = someOtherValue(u);
}

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(url);
listViewCookies.Items.Add(item);
```

The form of this code does not insert a collection of list items to a list view, instead it inserts a single list item with two values.

The first value is set repeatedly in the first loop, and the second in the second loop. You are constantly overwriting the same value, and at the end you are left with a single pair of values.

What you could do is something like:

```
//container for the first item of the pair
List<string> typedUrls = new List<string>(); 
foreach (string u in someCollection)
{
   typedUrls.Add(someValue(u));
}

//container for the second item of the pair
List<string> times = new List<string>(); 
foreach (string u in someOtherCollection)
{
    times.Add(someOtherValue(u));
}

//now loop the containers, and construct a string[] for each
//assuming that they have the exact same length
for (int i = 0; i < typedUrls.Count; i++)
{
    //create a string[]
    string[] stringItem = { typedUrls[i], times[i]};
    //construct a ListViewItem
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(stringItem);
    //add it to the listView
    listViewCookies.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: How can i get firefox history in a windows form and dislay in a listview using Sqlite database? SWeko You look expert in C#

Comment: That is a complex problem, with many sub-tasks. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137880/how-can-you-automate-firefox-from-c-sharp-application) to start you on the right foot.